# My accuracy stays around the same, what can I do to fix this

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

After finally fixing all the errors this code gave me, I have stumbled upon a new problem. This time it is the working model that supplies me with it. Here is the code I have created, this is now my third Deep Learning code I made and I am having a lot of fun making it, however, because I am a beginner in Python in general, some ideas are hard to grasp.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras as kr
from keras import layers
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from pandas import DataFrame


config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession(config=config)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

headers = ['id', 'rated', 'created_at', 'last_move_at', 'turns', 'victory_status', 'winner', 'increment_code',
           'white_id', 'white_rating', 'black_id', 'black_rating', 'moves', 'opening_eco', 'opening_name',
           'opening_ply']
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\games.csv', header=None, names=headers)
dataset = DataFrame(data)
dd = dataset.drop([0])
df = dd.drop(columns=['id', 'rated', 'opening_name', 'created_at', 'last_move_at', 'increment_code', 'white_id',
                      'black_id', 'opening_ply', 'opening_name', 'turns', 'victory_status', 'moves', 'opening_eco'],
             axis=1)

df['winner'] = df['winner'].map({'black': 0, 'white': 1})
y = df['winner']
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y)
X = df.drop('winner', axis=1)
X = X.astype("float32")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, encoded_y, test_size=0.2)
sc = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
scaled_X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(12, 2)))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=kr.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(scaled_X_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_data=(scaled_X_test,
                                                                                                    y_test))
print(history.history)
score = model.evaluate(scaled_X_train, y_train, verbose=1)
```

My code seems to work fine with the first few epochs an increase in the accuracy. After that however, the accuracy doesn't seem to be making any progress anymore and lands on a modest accuracy of around 0.610, or specifically as seen below. With no idea on how to get this to be higher, I have come to you to ask you the question: 'How do I fix this?'

```
Epoch 1/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6386 - accuracy: 0.5463 - val_loss: 0.6208 - val_accuracy: 0.5783
Epoch 2/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6098 - accuracy: 0.6091 - val_loss: 0.6078 - val_accuracy: 0.5960
Epoch 3/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6055 - accuracy: 0.6102 - val_loss: 0.6177 - val_accuracy: 0.5833
Epoch 4/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6042 - accuracy: 0.6129 - val_loss: 0.6138 - val_accuracy: 0.5850
Epoch 5/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6041 - accuracy: 0.6106 - val_loss: 0.6233 - val_accuracy: 0.5763
Epoch 6/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6046 - accuracy: 0.6097 - val_loss: 0.6276 - val_accuracy: 0.5733
Epoch 7/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6033 - accuracy: 0.6086 - val_loss: 0.6238 - val_accuracy: 0.5733
Epoch 8/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6023 - accuracy: 0.6116 - val_loss: 0.6202 - val_accuracy: 0.5770
Epoch 9/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6030 - accuracy: 0.6091 - val_loss: 0.6210 - val_accuracy: 0.5738
Epoch 10/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6028 - accuracy: 0.6098 - val_loss: 0.6033 - val_accuracy: 0.5932
Epoch 11/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 0.6166 - val_accuracy: 0.5780
Epoch 12/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6104 - val_loss: 0.6026 - val_accuracy: 0.5947
Epoch 13/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6243 - val_accuracy: 0.5733
Epoch 14/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 876us/step - loss: 0.6027 - accuracy: 0.6098 - val_loss: 0.6176 - val_accuracy: 0.5775
Epoch 15/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6029 - accuracy: 0.6091 - val_loss: 0.6286 - val_accuracy: 0.5690
Epoch 16/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 876us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6083 - val_loss: 0.6104 - val_accuracy: 0.5840
Epoch 17/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 876us/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6102 - val_loss: 0.6039 - val_accuracy: 0.5897
Epoch 18/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6113 - val_loss: 0.6046 - val_accuracy: 0.5887
Epoch 19/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6083 - val_loss: 0.6074 - val_accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 20/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 971us/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6089 - val_loss: 0.6194 - val_accuracy: 0.5738
Epoch 21/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 876us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6093 - val_accuracy: 0.5857
Epoch 22/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6097 - val_loss: 0.6154 - val_accuracy: 0.5773
Epoch 23/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6027 - accuracy: 0.6104 - val_loss: 0.6044 - val_accuracy: 0.5895
Epoch 24/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6015 - accuracy: 0.6112 - val_loss: 0.6305 - val_accuracy: 0.5710
Epoch 25/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6016 - accuracy: 0.6114 - val_loss: 0.6067 - val_accuracy: 0.5867
Epoch 26/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6102 - val_loss: 0.6140 - val_accuracy: 0.5800
Epoch 27/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6075 - val_loss: 0.6190 - val_accuracy: 0.5755
Epoch 28/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6029 - accuracy: 0.6087 - val_loss: 0.6337 - val_accuracy: 0.5666
Epoch 29/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6095 - val_loss: 0.6089 - val_accuracy: 0.5840
Epoch 30/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6026 - accuracy: 0.6106 - val_loss: 0.6273 - val_accuracy: 0.5690
Epoch 31/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6083 - val_loss: 0.6146 - val_accuracy: 0.5785
Epoch 32/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6116 - val_loss: 0.6093 - val_accuracy: 0.5837
Epoch 33/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6096 - val_loss: 0.6139 - val_accuracy: 0.5780
Epoch 34/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6087 - val_loss: 0.6090 - val_accuracy: 0.5850
Epoch 35/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6096 - val_loss: 0.6127 - val_accuracy: 0.5810
Epoch 36/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 876us/step - loss: 0.6024 - accuracy: 0.6091 - val_loss: 0.6001 - val_accuracy: 0.5975
Epoch 37/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6027 - accuracy: 0.6104 - val_loss: 0.6083 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 38/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6090 - val_loss: 0.6073 - val_accuracy: 0.5875
Epoch 39/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6023 - accuracy: 0.6109 - val_loss: 0.6149 - val_accuracy: 0.5785
Epoch 40/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6085 - val_loss: 0.6175 - val_accuracy: 0.5758
Epoch 41/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6079 - val_loss: 0.6062 - val_accuracy: 0.5865
Epoch 42/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6097 - val_loss: 0.6060 - val_accuracy: 0.5867
Epoch 43/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6082 - val_loss: 0.6074 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 44/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6096 - val_loss: 0.6150 - val_accuracy: 0.5785
Epoch 45/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6014 - accuracy: 0.6112 - val_loss: 0.6241 - val_accuracy: 0.5740
Epoch 46/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6023 - accuracy: 0.6111 - val_loss: 0.6118 - val_accuracy: 0.5815
Epoch 47/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6073 - val_loss: 0.6110 - val_accuracy: 0.5835
Epoch 48/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6074 - val_loss: 0.6107 - val_accuracy: 0.5835
Epoch 49/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6097 - val_loss: 0.6081 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 50/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6014 - accuracy: 0.6078 - val_loss: 0.6214 - val_accuracy: 0.5770
Epoch 51/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6023 - accuracy: 0.6093 - val_loss: 0.6011 - val_accuracy: 0.5952
Epoch 52/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6028 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 0.6013 - val_accuracy: 0.5950
Epoch 53/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6079 - val_loss: 0.6158 - val_accuracy: 0.5770
Epoch 54/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6103 - val_loss: 0.6080 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 55/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6095 - val_loss: 0.6180 - val_accuracy: 0.5775
Epoch 56/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6106 - val_accuracy: 0.5842
Epoch 57/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6078 - val_loss: 0.6232 - val_accuracy: 0.5740
Epoch 58/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6155 - val_accuracy: 0.5788
Epoch 59/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6026 - accuracy: 0.6119 - val_loss: 0.6150 - val_accuracy: 0.5775
Epoch 60/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6014 - accuracy: 0.6092 - val_loss: 0.5982 - val_accuracy: 0.6012
Epoch 61/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6087 - val_loss: 0.6022 - val_accuracy: 0.5947
Epoch 62/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6265 - val_accuracy: 0.5735
Epoch 63/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 899us/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6172 - val_accuracy: 0.5775
Epoch 64/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 982us/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6116 - val_accuracy: 0.5815
Epoch 65/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 969us/step - loss: 0.6015 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6230 - val_accuracy: 0.5738
Epoch 66/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 0.6058 - val_accuracy: 0.5870
Epoch 67/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6103 - val_loss: 0.6250 - val_accuracy: 0.5723
Epoch 68/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6015 - accuracy: 0.6109 - val_loss: 0.6129 - val_accuracy: 0.5790
Epoch 69/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6016 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6061 - val_accuracy: 0.5867
Epoch 70/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6031 - accuracy: 0.6084 - val_loss: 0.5999 - val_accuracy: 0.5980
Epoch 71/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6080 - val_loss: 0.6065 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 72/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6015 - accuracy: 0.6097 - val_loss: 0.6193 - val_accuracy: 0.5745
Epoch 73/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6024 - accuracy: 0.6081 - val_loss: 0.6183 - val_accuracy: 0.5753
Epoch 74/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6017 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 0.6165 - val_accuracy: 0.5778
Epoch 75/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6016 - accuracy: 0.6091 - val_loss: 0.6008 - val_accuracy: 0.5955
Epoch 76/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 0.6235 - val_accuracy: 0.5733
Epoch 77/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6083 - val_loss: 0.6178 - val_accuracy: 0.5773
Epoch 78/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6016 - accuracy: 0.6099 - val_loss: 0.6232 - val_accuracy: 0.5715
Epoch 79/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6024 - accuracy: 0.6052 - val_loss: 0.6262 - val_accuracy: 0.5705
Epoch 80/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6050 - val_loss: 0.6150 - val_accuracy: 0.5785
Epoch 81/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6011 - accuracy: 0.6111 - val_loss: 0.6177 - val_accuracy: 0.5755
Epoch 82/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6087 - val_loss: 0.6124 - val_accuracy: 0.5783
Epoch 83/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6090 - val_loss: 0.6107 - val_accuracy: 0.5833
Epoch 84/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6025 - accuracy: 0.6102 - val_loss: 0.6110 - val_accuracy: 0.5800
Epoch 85/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 0.6077 - val_accuracy: 0.5845
Epoch 86/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6016 - accuracy: 0.6069 - val_loss: 0.6109 - val_accuracy: 0.5798
Epoch 87/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6092 - val_loss: 0.6117 - val_accuracy: 0.5798
Epoch 88/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6021 - accuracy: 0.6089 - val_loss: 0.6105 - val_accuracy: 0.5808
Epoch 89/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6020 - accuracy: 0.6063 - val_loss: 0.6190 - val_accuracy: 0.5753
Epoch 90/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6022 - accuracy: 0.6083 - val_loss: 0.6211 - val_accuracy: 0.5740
Epoch 91/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6023 - accuracy: 0.6058 - val_loss: 0.6117 - val_accuracy: 0.5785
Epoch 92/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6077 - val_loss: 0.6200 - val_accuracy: 0.5740
Epoch 93/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6014 - accuracy: 0.6078 - val_loss: 0.6230 - val_accuracy: 0.5735
Epoch 94/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6018 - accuracy: 0.6087 - val_loss: 0.6113 - val_accuracy: 0.5810
Epoch 95/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6086 - val_loss: 0.6203 - val_accuracy: 0.5755
Epoch 96/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6013 - accuracy: 0.6088 - val_loss: 0.6273 - val_accuracy: 0.5693
Epoch 97/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6071 - val_loss: 0.6023 - val_accuracy: 0.5927
Epoch 98/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6023 - accuracy: 0.6072 - val_loss: 0.6093 - val_accuracy: 0.5810
Epoch 99/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 925us/step - loss: 0.6012 - accuracy: 0.6091 - val_loss: 0.6018 - val_accuracy: 0.5937
Epoch 100/100
321/321 [==============================] - 0s 973us/step - loss: 0.6015 - accuracy: 0.6092 - val_loss: 0.6255 - val_accuracy: 0.5710
```

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: My dataset is [20059, 16]. https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/chess

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a problem in your training data or model is too small.

By looking at the loss - which is obviously not changing at all - I'd say the problem is size of model. Try adding more neurons in dense layers.

Comment: I have tried that, but the accuracy stays the same. Whatever I try. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not sufficiently big enough to handle the data.
So, try increasing your model size.
However, increasing your model size makes it more vulnerable to overfitting, but using some [Dropout](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/) layers solves the issue.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(12, 2)))
model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.20))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Furthermore, a lower learning rate allows the model to get to a better accuracy & loss.
You can tweak the learning rate of the Adam optimizer when compiling,

```
model.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002), loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The default value of learning rate of the Adam optimizer is 0.001